# REACT NATIVE let me know how to store data from API into a list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to get json's length from API, then create buttons as many as json's length.

I tried to put the length into num_of_event, but it is just empty..

Please give me idea...

here is my code

```
const views1 = [];
export const renderButtons1 = (numOfBtns,tt) => {
    const views1 = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < numOfBtns; i++) {
        views1.push(
            <Button
                 key={parseInt(i)}
                 onPress={() => navigate('EventsList')}
                 title={tt}
                 color="#841584"
                 accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
             />);
    }

    return views1;
}
export default class Events extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        numOfEvents: 0,
        title:""
    };
}
componentDidMount() {
    const self = this;

    fetch('https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?location.address=glasgow&token=F7AWKEHKD6BW2TZKWO7N&expand=venue')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
            self.setState({numOfEvents: (responseJson.events).length},{title:responseJson.events[0]["name"]["text"]});
            console.log(responseJson.events[0]["name"]["text"])
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}
   render() {

    return (renderButtons1());
   } 
 .... 
}
```

num_of_event does not get any value...

Comment: You are pushing to `num_of_event` after your promise is completed asynchronously, thus when you try to push to `views1` synchronously, it happens before `num_of_event` gets populated.

Comment: thanks, how would I make them  synchronously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it's very confusing what you are doing with an array. If you only need the length why not store it as a number rather than pushing it into an array and then converting the array to string.
Also, you need to set the result of your async call to the state, so it will update when the promise is resolved. 
Here's how you could go about it:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        numOfEvents: 0
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    const self = this;

    fetch('https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?location.address=glasgow&token=F7AWKEHKD6BW2TZKWO7N&expand=venue')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            self.setState({numOfEvents: response.events.length});
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}

export const renderButtons1 = (numOfBtns) => {
    const views1 = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < numOfBtns; i++) {
        views1.push(
            <Button
                 key={parseInt(i)}
                 onPress={() => navigate('EventsList')}
                 title="Learn More"
                 color="#841584"
                 accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
             />);
    }

    return views1;
}

render() {
    return renderButtons1();
}
```

Comment: I think I have to put return renderButtons1(numOfEvents); , before I put, I got an error undefined is not an object(evaluation 'response.json().events.length')

Comment: I slightly updated the answer by moving response.json() to a separate then, that might be the problem. I don't think the order of declaring functions matters here, since you are only calling `renderButtons1` in the `render` method, which is below the const declaration.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, I posted the correct code,but I am  still not sure why I got the title prop of a button must be a string. as you can see,  In renderButtons1 there are 2 parameters ,      numOfBtns : how many times to create buttons , tt : it is the tile of event which is string. do you know why I got an error?

Comment: When you log `console.log(responseJson.events[0]["name"]["text"])` what does it show?

Comment: Also, since it helped, do you mind accepting my answer and upvoting it if it's not too much trouble?

Comment: sorry, I can't figure out why you are getting this error. I understand that the code works and does what you need it to do. why did you unaccept the answer? I think it's very unkind.